# Links with path parameters in JSF

Tags: jsf, path-parameter

In social networks like facebook you have links like `https://www.<socialNetwork>.com/<userName>/about` for example.

How can this be done with JSF? I mean, the way I am doing now is with parameters (which is quite ugly):

```
https://www.<socialNetwork>.com?userName=<userName>&page=about
```

I want the page to be bookmarkable, so I need the parameters in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some kind of URL Rewriter which converts your application URLs with parameters into something nicer. I can recommend either [Pretty Faces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) or [Rewrite](http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/), you can see comparison of those two [here](https://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/lincoln_baxter_iii/2012/03/migrating_from_prettyfaces_to_rewrite__simplicity_meets_power).